# Deriving Formula for Archimedes' Principle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

Let *B* be the buoyant force acting on an object and *W* be the weight of the fluid it displaces.

**I can't derive the formula for Archimedes' Principle:** *B = -W*

I have found plenty of derivations for *B = W* online and I understand them all. My problem is that, intuitively, the formula should be *B = -W* because the two forces act in opposite directions (the buoyant force acts upwards and the displaced fluid's weight acts downwards). Could someone derive this formula for me? The only explanation I can think of is this: the force of buoyancy just happens to be equal to the magnitude of the weight of the displaced fluid (*B = |W|*) and from context we know they act in opposite directions (therefore, *B = -W*). I'm not sure if you could directly derive *B = -W* and this is what I'm wondering.

(Edit: Just for clarity, I understand how to derive *B = W* but I cannot understand how to derive *B = -W*, which I think is the real formula for Archimedes' Principle.)

Comment: "I have found plenty of derivations for B = W online and I understand them all." I don't see how you can understand proofs of an equation that you believe to be wrong! In fact $B=W$ is to be interpreted as meaning that the *magnitudes* of the buoyancy force and the weight are equal. What really *would* be wrong is $\mathbf B =\mathbf W$ or $\vec B =\vec W$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the portion, P, of fluid that is displaced by the object, O. P used to occupy the space that O now occupies. P used to be in equilibrium, as we assume that the fluid was static throughout. Therefore

Resultant force on P from surrounding fluid = – Weight of P.

But now O occupies exactly the same space that P used to occupy, so it experiences exactly the same hydrostatic forces from the surrounding fluid that P used to experience. So

Resultant force on O from surrounding fluid = – Weight of P

That's it: Archimedes' Principle ($\vec B=-\vec W$ if you like)!

This derivation needs a small modification if the fluid is a liquid in a container of dimensions such that the fluid level will rise significantly (by an amount $h_0$, say) when O is introduced. In that case the normal force per unit area on O will be greater than that on P, but by the same amount ($h_0 \rho g$) at all points on O. It is easy to see that the *resultant* extra vertical force on O will be zero.
$$\left[\oint_\text{Surface of O} h_0\rho g \cos\theta\ dS=h_0\rho g\oint_\text{Surface of O} \cos\theta\ dS=0 \right]$$